# Returning record type

Tags: function, plsql

i need to declare record type and then return it in some way that I would be able to read that record from my Java application.

So lets say I have table :

```
Player
------------
Player_id
First_Name
Second_Name
Team
```

then i declare record type :

```
DECLARE
   type Player_type is record
      (First_Name  varchar(25),
      Second_Name  varchar(25),
      Team varchar(25));
BEGIN
     SELECT First_Name, Second_Name , Team INTO Player_type FROM Player;
END;
```

So this is all i can do but I need to do function that gets Player_id as an argument and return record type, then this record type I need to read from Java application. But I dont really know what to do now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept here is you can achieve this in two ways

1) By using complex objects types
2) By using refcursor

The 1st one would be a bit complex to handle from JAVA part and the code is illustrated below.

```
--CREATE schema level OBJECT type and NESTED table type to RETURN it in FUNCTION

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE player_type IS OBJECT
(First_Name  varchar(25),
      Second_Name  varchar(25),
      Team varchar(25)
)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE player_tab IS TABLE OF player_type
/

--FUNCTION Body

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION player_attribute
(
p_player_id IN NUMBER
)
RETURN player_tab
AS
ply_tb player_tab;
BEGIN

    SELECT First_Name, 
    Second_Name , 
    Team 
    BULK COLLECT 
    INTO Ply_tb 
    FROM Player
RETURN ply_tb;

END;
/
```

And the 2nd approach will be a bit easy just to pass the whole output as refcursor as shown below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION player_attribute
(
p_player_id IN NUMBER
)
return sys_refcursor
AS
p_lst sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
Open p_lst FOR
    SELECT First_Name, 
    Second_Name , 
    Team 
    FROM Player
    WHERE player_id = p_player_id;

RETURN p_lst; 

END;
/
```